# How to debug an Android app that says "unfortunately <app> stopped working"?

Tags: android

This is my java class, MainActivity.java.

Basically I'm trying to create a button performing addition on variable `i`. Everything seems to be correct as far as I learnt until now. I am getting an error message on my emulator saying:

> unfortunately myfirstandroidapp stopped working.

Code:

```
package com.example.android.myfirstandroidapp;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int i = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        final TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                i++;
                txtView.setText("i value is:"+i);
            }
        });
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

This is my layout.xml

main_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.myfirstandroidapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your value is:0"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Add One"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please put a real title, this is not a forum.

Comment: for asking a question check logcat when your app stopped...then if you can't find out the problem, search the error, and you cant find the answer or similar question asked before then post your problem as a Question here

Answer (score 4):

You need to call setContentView() before initializing any View.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    final TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            i++;
            txtView.setText("i value is:"+i);
        }
    });

}
```